# Java recursion with one return statement

Tags: java, recursion

Is it possible to add the numbers 1 to n recursively in Java with one return statement? How would you change the standard solution:

```
public static int sum(int n) {
   if(n == 1) return n;
    else return n + sum(n - 1);
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
return n == 1 ? n : n + sum(n-1);
```

Answer (score 6):

You could use simple maths without recursion:

```
public static int sum(int n) {
   return n * (n + 1) / 2;
}
```

Comment: Wow, that’s an amazing formula did you figure that out yourself?

Comment: @DCR This problem has been known for quite a while, this formula is widely accessible on the internet

Comment: If you want to get rid of the division use `>> 1`. There's no need to, though. The compiler will make this trivial optimization on its own. Exploiting integer overflow is bizarre.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, by making use of the *ternary operator* :

```
public static int sum(int n) {
    return n == 1 ? n : n + sum(n - 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  public static int sum(int n) {
      return n == 1 ? 1 : n + sum(n-1);
  }
```